# How could I make something like QFutureWatcher by boost

Tags: c++, qt, boost

I want to execute some heavy task in the background without blocking the gui when I waiting for the return value, with QFutureWatcher, things are easy

example from Qt5.3 document

```
// Instantiate the objects and connect to the finished signal.
MyClass myObject;
QFutureWatcher<int> watcher;
connect(&watcher, SIGNAL(finished()), &myObject, SLOT(handleFinished()));

// Start the computation.
QFuture<int> future = QtConcurrent::run(...);
watcher.setFuture(future);
```

How could I make something like the "finished" signal of QFutureWatcher with the help of boost(I need the handleFinished() execute in the main thread)?

Although QFutureWatcher is there and kicking, but our projects are depend on Qt3, Qt4 and Qt5 by now(priority of upgrading the apps from Qt3, Qt4 to Qt5 is pretty low), that is why we want to implement the back end tasks by boost and standard library

Edit 1 :
just found the answer, boost::future provide a pretty elegant solution for this kind of scenario, just use future.then

```
future.then([](boost::future<int> f) { return print_value(f.get()); });
```

Edit 2 :
the function called by future then do no execute in the main thread, how could I make it execute it the main thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the handler function to run in the main thread, it has to be in the event loop.

In that case you could do it like this:

(I use `C++11` but it could be easily done with `boost::thread` or `QThread`)

```
struct Object:public QObject {


    Q_OBJECT
    std::thread thr;

    Object(QObject *parent):QObject(parent){}
    ~Object(){
       if(thr.joinable())
           thr.join();
    }
public slots:
    void handler(int);

};

    ...
    auto obj = new Object(parent); //store it somewhere  
    obj->thr=std::thread([](Object * obj){
                      int ret=run_something();
                      //PostEvent on the event queue where the obj Object resides
                      QMetaObject::invokeMethod(obj, "handler",
                                                Qt::QueuedConnection,
                                                Q_ARG(int,ret));
                     }
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any library for that, especially if it's a one time thingy and not used for synchronization between iterations or something like that:

```
volatile bool done = false;
volatile int retvalue = 0;

void workerThread() {
    retvalue = some_function_doing_math();
    done = true;
}

void parentLocationCalling() {
    done = false;
    myCustomThread.run(workerThread);
    for (;!done;) sleep(10);
    // retvalue now contains the result
}
```

If you've got C++11, then it's even easier to be done, since you won't need any platform specific code (untested):

```
#include <thread>

void workerThread(int &ret) {
    ret = some_function_doing_math();
}

void parentLocationCalling() {
    int result;
    std::thread worker(workerThread, std::ref(result));
    worker.join();
}
```

Of course you might want to still process window messages and/or update your window while waiting, which isn't considered in these examples.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the reason i want a QFutureWatcher like infrastructure is that I don't want the main thread be blocked(join) or calling a sleep method if the while loop(waiting the future get the return value).

Comment: So the thread is supposed to continue with something else? If you've got some other loop that's running anyway, then you're able to check there whether the thread is still running (similar to my first snippet).